# My progress bar hiding behind other layouts

Tags: android

I have included a progress bar in my relative layout, but it is running behind the layout. Is there any way I can bring it in front show that it show when the page is loading.

[Sorry, I'm pasting whole XML file, cause I don't know where to put progress bar! as I'm newbie, I want you to help me. Sorry again!]

Code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/backgroundcolor"
    tools:context="com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Activity.AddReminderActivity">

    <!--TODO:-> Toolbar Layout-->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/toolbarcolor"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:title="@string/title_add_reminder" />


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_relative"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


 <include layout="@layout/row_progress_bar" />

            <!--TODO:-> Parent Layout-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                <!--TODO:-> Title & Category Layout-->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/view_margin_top">

                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/dialog_main_linear_layout_style"
                        android:padding="8dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">


                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/title"
                                style="@style/heading_textview_style1"
                                android:text="@string/heading_title"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/heading_text_size" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text=" *"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorRed"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/title_layout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <ImageView
                                style="@style/vector_image_style"
                                android:tint="?attr/iconcolor"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_view_heading" />


                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/et_title"
                                style="@style/text_color"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
                                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorIconLightGray"
                                android:digits="0123456789 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ अआइईउऊऋएऐओऔकखगघङचछजझञाटठडढणतथदधनपफबभमयरलवशषसहक्षत्रज्ञ ा ि ी ु ू ृ े ै ो ौ ं ः "
                                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:maxLength="25"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                android:textSize="17sp" />


                        </LinearLayout>

                        <!--TODO:-> Title error-->
                        <include
                            android:id="@+id/tv_title_error"
                            layout="@layout/row_error_textview" />


                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/layout_category"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <Spinner
                                android:id="@+id/spin_list"
                                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                                android:backgroundTint="?attr/iconcolor"
                                android:dropDownVerticalOffset="17dp"
                                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/input_text_size" />


                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_selected_category"
                                style="@style/text_color"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/circle_card1"
                                android:text="@string/hint_select_category"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/input_text_size" />

                            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                                android:id="@+id/circle_card1"
                                android:layout_width="25dp"
                                android:layout_height="25dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:elevation="12dp"
                                android:innerRadius="0dp"
                                android:shape="ring"
                                android:thicknessRatio="0"
                                app:cardCornerRadius="13dp">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/category_image"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                    android:visibility="visible"
                                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp" />


                                <Button
                                    android:id="@+id/custom_category_image"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                    android:background="@drawable/bg_circle_btn"
                                    android:text="A"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                    android:textSize="12dp"
                                    android:visibility="gone"
                                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_black_24dp" />

                            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


                        </RelativeLayout>





                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorDarkerGray" />

                <!--TODO:-> Amount Layout-->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_amount"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_margin_top">


                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/dialog_main_linear_layout_style"
                        android:padding="8dp">


                        <TextView
                            style="@style/heading_textview_style"
                            android:text="@string/heading_amount"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/heading_text_size" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/iv_amount"
                                style="@style/vector_image_style"
                                android:tint="?attr/iconcolor"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/currency_inr" />

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/et_amount"
                                style="@style/text_color"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorIconLightGray"
                                android:hint="0.00"
                                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                                android:maxLength="7"
                                android:textSize="17sp" />

                        </LinearLayout>


                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/layout_payment_option"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:visibility="visible">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_selected_payment_mode"
                                style="@style/text_color"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/circle_card2"
                                android:gravity="end"
                                android:text="@string/select_payment"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/input_text_size" />

                            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                                android:id="@+id/circle_card2"
                                android:layout_width="25dp"
                                android:layout_height="25dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:elevation="12dp"
                                android:innerRadius="0dp"
                                android:shape="ring"
                                android:thicknessRatio="0"
                                app:cardCornerRadius="13dp">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/payment_image"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp"></ImageView>
                            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                        </RelativeLayout>




                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorDarkerGray" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:text="Select Date and Time"
                        style="@style/text_color"
                        android:textSize="16sp"

                        />

                    <!--TODO:-> Due date Layout-->
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout_due_date"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_margin_top">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_due_date"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:tint="?attr/iconcolor"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon_date" />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/date_layout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_due_date">

                            <TextView
                                style="@style/text_color"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/heading_due_date"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/heading_text_size" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_due_date"
                                style="@style/text_color"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_gravity="end"
                                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                                android:hint="YYYY-MM-DD"
                                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/input_text_size" />


                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <!--TODO:-> Due date error-->
                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/tv_due_date_error"
                        layout="@layout/row_error_textview" />

                    <!--TODO:-> Alarm Layout-->
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout_alarm_time"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/layout_due_date"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_margin_top"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_alarm_time"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:tint="?attr/iconcolor"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon_alarm" />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_alarm_time"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                style="@style/text_color"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/heading_alarm_time"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/heading_text_size" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_alarm_time"
                                style="@style/text_color"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_gravity="end"
                                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                                android:hint="HH:MM"
                                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/input_text_size" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_error_alarm_time"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Please select Alarm Time"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorRed"
                                android:visibility="gone" />


                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <!--TODO:-> Alarm error-->
                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/tv_time_error"
                        layout="@layout/row_error_textview" />


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/frequency_layout"
                        style="@style/sub_relative_layout_style">


                        <TextView
                            style="@style/sub_text_view_style"
                            android:text="Alarm Frequency" />


                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/collapse"
                            style="@style/visibilities_image_style"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:visibility="visible"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/expand"
                            style="@style/visibilities_image_style"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_up_black_24dp" />

                    </RelativeLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorDarkerGray" />

                <!--TODO:-> Note Layout-->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_notes"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/layout_repeat"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_margin_top">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_note"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                        android:tint="?attr/iconcolor"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp" />


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/note_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_note"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/text_color"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/heading_note"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/heading_text_size" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/note_desc"
                            android:textColor="?attr/textcolor"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                            android:maxLines="4" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorDarkerGray" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**row_progress_bar:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteAccent"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: Move include at end of parent layout before.

Comment: Try moving **<include layout="@layout/row_progress_bar" />** after LinearLayout or add an **elevation of 5dp** to your ProgressBar